# Npm package has too many dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies, npm-install

Im new to this all npm thing and I have a question about dependencies.
I started the React tutorial and I have been asked to run the following command:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

also, for a side project I also rn this following command in the same directory:

```
npm install react-chartjs-2 chart.js
```

And suddenly, my node_modules contains 800+ folders of packages.

So I found this site that tells you how many packages your package depends on and it showed me that I depend on only 100+ packages.
I know the meaning of `npm install`.

I find it really unexplainedable, I will appreaciate any help from your side.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What site is that? Perhaps it only shows you the direct dependencies, or maybe just how many dependencies, not considering each version that's required by various sub-dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

install npm-remote-ls globally and check the dependencies of any package you want

```
npm install npm-remote-ls -g
```

checking react dependencies: `npm-remote-ls react`

Comment: So I used npm-remote-ls, it looks like it dows not depends on 800+ packages. Where did it came from?

Comment: since npm@3.0.0 : Your dependencies will
now be installed
maximally flat. Insofar as
is possible, all of your
dependencies, and their
dependencies, and THEIR
dependencies will be
installed in your project's
node_modules folder with
no nesting. You'll only
see modules nested
underneath one another
when two (or more)
modules have conflicting
dependencies.